# Grouping the data based on the values of 1 column and then printing it in row format in Excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in the format

```
1   45  
1   34  
1   35  
1   36  
1   37  
1   38  
1   23  
2   24  
2   25  
2   26  
2   27  
3   28  
3   29
```

And I want output like

```
1   45  34  35  36  37  38 23    
2   24  25  26  27  
3   28  29
```

I have tried using macro but I am unable to do. Kindly help and solve it by macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub DataReorganizer()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long, L As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    L = 4
    Cells(K, L).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(K, L + 1).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value
    L = L + 2

    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Cells(K, L) = Cells(i, 2)
            L = L + 1
        Else
            L = 4
            K = K + 1
            Cells(K, L) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(K, L + 1) = Cells(i, 2)
            L = L + 2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly till the row number reached its extreme value of 1048576; once it exceeds that value, the code is not working. Any solution for that?

Comment: **Where shall we put the extra values ??**

Comment: The extra values are not displaying in Excel-2013 but it can be visualized easily in text format(tab delimiter). I am also curious to know, is there any way to include more rows than the maximum limit specified in Excel 2013?

Comment: By far, the simplest approach would be to use more than one worksheet.......once we get to the bottom row, we would move to the next worksheet and start at the top.............This is what is normally done if we are inputting a very large **.csv** file or some other kind of text file.